# Why is INSERT made after em.persist in FlushModeType.COMMIT?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have set *FlushModeType* to **COMMIT**, but right after em.persist() call, the INSERT is made to database. I expect *Hibernate* to write changes to database only at the end of transaction, but it seems to work differently.

Little code to illustrate the problem:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl1")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class TopLevelEntity {}

@Entity
@Table(name="tbl2")
public class MyEntity extends TopLevelEntity { 
  AnotherEntity anotherEntity;      
  //getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class AnotherEntity { }

public void someTransaction() {
  em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);

  MyEntity e = new MyEntity();

  em.persist(e);

  e.setProp1(someVal1);
  e.setProp2(someVal2);

}
```

Here I expect, that the actual INSERT will be made at the end of method, right after setProp2() call.
But Hibernate does the insert right after calling `em.persist()`.

Can somebody explain me this behaviour?

**Edit:**
I even tried using FlushMode.MANUAL for Hibernate *Session*, but it performs **INSERT** after `em.persist` anyway. So, is there no way to manually control when *flush* is done?

**Edit2:**
Here is the issue, which I'm facing. I have an entity `A` which *has-a* entity `B`. Entity `B` doesn't exist yet during the call to `em.persist(a)`, and I have a 'CONSTRAINT CHECK (B IS NOT NULL) in the database`. The only workaround which I found is to use *deferred constraint* in Oracle. However, this solution is vendor-specific and doesn't really satisfy me.

**Edit3:**
**Cascade** seems like a good solution, but in our project we're not allowed to use it. We're encouraged to manually control all the inserts and updates.

Comment: To answer this question, it could be useful to know how MyEntity is mapped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FlushMode Commit does not guarantee that the commit will happen at transaction commit. It is more of a hint for the provider (implementator of specs, like Hibernate here), but he can do it whenever he chooses. If you want to persists/update a bean which has a new dependency that doesn't exist yet in the database. use Cascade on persists/merge operations to persist it as well. IF you declared a field/dependency as not-nullable than it's normal for JPA not to let you save an entity with that field/dependecy null, as it enforces the constrains you put on it. What you want to do there is pretty much a hack/workaround around the JPA specs. you either make that field/dependency nullable if in fact it can sometimes be null, or you make sure that it's never null (and cascaded if it's new value) when you persist the parent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately we're not allowed to use cascades in our project. As for the nullable suggestion. Well, first of all, it's not naturally nullable, there is always mandatory one-to-one relationship between these entities. But even if I mark it as nullable, I'm afraid it's not going to change anything, because Hibernate issues INSERT statement to database after calling em.persist, which in turn throws ConstraintViolationException.

Comment: Well, then I guess you can try using an Entity Lifecycle listener, that intercepts the entity before it is updater or created, checks if it has a null dependency and if it does, it will first create that needed dependency, persistit it and add it to the bean, and then let the initial update/persist continue : http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28221/cmp30cfg015.htm

Comment: The problem is that the dependent Entity can't be created at that moment. I know it might sound weird, but I'm working on a quite large project, and I can't change the business workflow, designed by our architects. But thanks for the suggestion, I'll try to make something up.

Answer (score 1):

Because COMMIT as mode does not guarantee that flush happens only during commit. Section 3.2.4 in specification:

> If FlushModeType.COMMIT is specified, flushing will occur at
>   transaction commit; the persistence provider is permitted, but not
>   required, to perform to flush at other times.

Comment: OK, I read this myself recently. But then, what's the point of setting FlushMode if it doesn't guarantee when the flush occurs?

Comment: I think purpose is not to strictly define how flush is performed. It is more about giving provider possibility (but not forcing) to make optimized implementation. When queried via entity manager with COMMIT- flush mode: are updates seen is unspecified (so it doesn't guarantee that updates are visible/unvisible). For me it is little bit as with calling Integer.valueOf(32768), result is not guaranteed to be cached one, but it can be.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll wait for some time if others have something to say about it. Also, see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Because of hibernates firstlevelcache